# Don't repeat Array item in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift3, xcode8

I am new to programming. I am trying to make a simple game in iOS. I have an array with a list of names and I have two buttons that randomly select items out of the array.

My question is what line of code do I need to add to my project to remove an ARRAY ITEM after it has been selected.

```
var playerName = ["James", "John", "Paul", "Chris", "BoB", "Sam", "Mike", "Jason"]


//IBOutlets
@IBOutlet weak var player1BTN: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var player2BTN: UIButton!


//IBActions
@IBAction func player1BTNpressed(_ sender: Any) {
    print("player 1")

    //Randomize player from 0 to 26
    let player1 = Int(arc4random_uniform(26))

    // Change Button Title Text
    player1BTN.setTitle((playerName[player1]), for: UIControlState.normal)

}

@IBAction func player2BTNpressed(_ sender: Any) {
    print ("player 2")

    //Randomize player from 0 to 26
    let player2 = Int(arc4random_uniform(26))

    // Change Button Title Text
    player2BTN.setTitle((playerName[player2]), for: UIControlState.normal)

}
```

hope this makes sense. thanks for the help.

Comment: Here's the documentation on Array: http://swiftdoc.org/v3.1/type/Array/ Now, look through that and see if you can find how you might find "up" in the array and then, having found it, how you might remove it from the array.

Comment: I hope this question is better structured.

Comment: But did you do as I suggested in my previous comment? I showed you the docs; did you examine them and think, _yourself_, about how to _remove_ an item from an array?

Comment: yes I did look at the documentation that you provided(Thank you for that). I figured that I would need to add a remove statement.  I believe that I understand that if I was just selecting the items in order I would at a statement like {playerName.remove(at: 0)} which would remove the first item in the array after I used it. However I am have trouble wrapping my mind around how to remove a randomly selected array item.

Comment: The random selection starts with an index number. `player1` and `player2` are index numbers. By an amazing coincidence, an index number is exactly what `remove(at:)` wants.

Comment: Ok so keep in mind I am new to all of this, but what I think you are saying is that I should add {playerName.remove(at: player1)}.  If so I still need to figure out exactly where in my code to insert this(but I have an idea).  But if this is the answer it's way to simple.  I have to be missing something.

Answer (score 0):

```
     Please try this code, it might be helped you:-

        var playerName = ["James", "John", "Paul", "Chris", "BoB", "Sam", "Mike", "Jason"]

                let item = "Chris"

                if let index = playerName.index(of: item) {
                    playerName.remove(at: index)
                    print(playerName)
                }

Output like this:- ["James", "John", "Paul", "BoB", "Sam", "Mike", "Jason"]
```

Comment: What it did was it removed the item in the "let item = "NAME"" but my issue is that the item that is selected is random